# In Python: Why does a Numpy array returned in a method have to be stored in the instance?

Tags: arrays, numpy, audio, python-3.5, pyaudio

The issue is a bit complicated so I need to give you the full story:

I'm trying to create basic sound using the package **pyaudio**.
The **pyaudio** module asks for a callback function that reads audio data.
It basically looks like this:

```
def callback():
    return sound.readframes()
```

I have a class that provides audio data. It creates a signal by indexing a numpy array that contains a wave length of a basic wave form. It basically looks like this:

```
class Wave(object):
    data = [] # one wavelength of a basic waveform like a sine wave will be stored here

    def readframes(self):
        indices = # the indices for the next frames 
                  # based on a frequency and the current position
        return self.data[indices]

class SineWave(Wave):
    data = # points of a sine wave in a numpy array

sound = SineWave()

# pyaudio now reads audio data in a non-blocking callback mode
```

Now to the problem:

There was noise between each call to **readframes** or each block of audio data. The sound itself was still intact, but there was an additional clicking. Increasing the size of the returned data block also increased the time between each click. I still don't quite know what caused the noise, but I fixed it by storing the returned numpy array in the instance instead of returning it directly.

This causes noise:

```
return self.data[indices]
```

This does not cause noise:

```
+ self.result = self.data[indices]
+ return self.result
```

It can't be an alteration of the data that causes the noise or else this wouldn't fix it. Why does the result have to be stored in the instance?

**Update:**

I also have to mention that the noise doesn't occur everytime I run the script. It occurs randomly about 50% of the runs. Either the noise appears right at the start and won't go away or it doesn't appear at all.
It looks like an issue with the initialization of the sound device, but how that could be related to my fix is a mistery.

Here is code that reproduces the noise problem:

```
import pyaudio
import time
from numpy import sin, linspace, arange, pi, float32, uint32

SR = 44100  # sampling rate
FPB = 2048  # frames per buffer

class SineWave(object):
    """A sine wave"""

    data_size = 2**10
    data = sin(linspace(0, 2*pi, data_size, endpoint=False, dtype=float32))

    def __init__(self, frequency):
        self.pos = 0
        self.fq = frequency
        self.ppf = self.data_size * self.fq / SR  # points per frame

    def readframes(self):
        size = FPB
        pos = self.pos
        indices = (arange(pos, size+pos)*self.ppf).astype(uint32) & (self.data_size-1)
        self.pos = (self.pos + size) % SR
        self.result = self.data[indices]
        return self.data[indices]

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    return sound.readframes(), pyaudio.paContinue

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(4),
                channels=1,
                rate=SR,
                output=True,
                stream_callback=callback,
                frames_per_buffer=FPB)

sound = SineWave(440)
stream.start_stream()
time.sleep(2)
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

On my system the noise appears in about 90% of the runs.

Changing

```
return self.data[indices]
```

to

```
return self.result
```

fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a difference whether you store the intermediate array in the instance or not. I suspect there is some other problem going on that causes the error you're experiencing. Can you provide code that actually runs and exhibits the problem?

If you want to see a (hopefully!) working implementation, have a look at the [play()](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sounddevice.play) function of the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) module, especially at the `loop` argument. With this, you should be able to play your waveform repeatedly.

The only thing you need to store in the instance, is the frame index where you left off, just to continue with the following frame index in the next callback (and of course wrap around in the end). You should also consider the case where your wave form is shorter than an audio block. It might even be *much* shorter. I solved that by using a recursive function call, see [the code](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/68a30f8da513ae15e517c5d27d4ae4755ca9f368/sounddevice.py#L2263).

---

UPDATE:

It's indeed quite strange that assigning to `self` "solves" your problem. I think this has something to do with how PyAudio interprets the returned array as Python buffer.

You should rewrite your code using the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) module, which properly supports NumPy arrays and has a sane API for the callback function.

It's easy, just use this callback function:

```
def callback(outdata, frames, time, status):
    if status:
        print(status)
    outdata[:, 0] = sound.readframes()
```

And start the stream with:

```
import sounddevice as sd
stream = sd.OutputStream(
    channels=1, samplerate=SR, callback=callback, blocksize=FPB)
```

Apart from that, your code is flawed since it doesn't do any interpolation when reading from the wavetable.

Comment: I added a working code sample which produces the noise. The issue is not a bug in the code, it must have something to do with what is going on in the background, because the noise doesn't appear everytime I run the script.

Comment: @uzumaki I've extended my answer.